# Webbrowser like Mozilla control for VB.NET question

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, mozilla

I want to use mozilla control in my application..
But

when i use Webbrowsercontrol i just use

```
webbrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

but this commant is not working with mozilla control ant when we try to navigate to any web address it gives following exception.

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Which Mozilla control are you using?

Comment: Mozilla ActiveX Control 1.7.12

Comment: http://www.brothersoft.com/mozilla-activex-control-78221.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That control is based on Firefox 1.5. [There are a few projects on Google code](http://code.google.com/query/#p=gears&q=windows%20forms%20firefox) that may work with later Firefox versions.